# SAS code to get the last FT that comes after BP

Tags: sas

Input/output image of he query is given below:

[image: Input/output image of he query is given below]

Answer (score 0):

This is what by-group processing is for.

```
proc sort data=yourdata;
by SEQ VAR1 TIME;
run;

data yourNewData;
  set yourdata;
  by SEQ VAR1 TIME;

if VAR1="BP" or last.VAR1 then output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the power of Retain and automatic variables created by 'by' statement. Here is your working solution:

```
proc sort data=yourData;
by Seq Time var1;
run;

data yourData1;
set yourData;
by Seq;
retain GroupID;
if first.Seq then GroupID=.;
if var1="BP" then GroupID = sum(GroupID, 1);
run;

data yourData2;
set yourData1;
by Seq GroupID;
if (GroupID ne .) and (var1="BP" or last.GroupID=1);
drop GroupID;
run;
```